# Dockerizing react for production not working

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

I have created a `Dockerfile` and `Docker-compose.yml` for containerzing my `create-react-app` to production. My problem of understanding is how should I create the production build if the scripts that are needed to run the command are `dev-dependencies`?
Also I can`t find anything on [deployment docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment).

```
 > [builder 7/7] RUN yarn build:
#13 0.507 yarn run v1.22.19
#13 0.556 $ react-scripts build
#13 0.579 /bin/sh: react-scripts: not found
#13 0.590 error Command failed with exit code 127.
#13 0.590 info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
------
executor failed running [/bin/sh -c yarn build]: exit code: 127
ERROR: Service 'app' failed to build : Build failed
`docker-compose` process finished with exit code 1
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^18.1.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.17.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",   <--- THIS WILL BE USED FOR PRODUCTION
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",   <--- THIS WILL NOT BE INSTALLED WITH --production FLAG
    "tailwindcss": "^3.0.24",
    "typescript": "^4.6.3"
  }
}
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM node:18-alpine AS builder
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Add a work directory
WORKDIR /app

# Cache and Install dependencies
COPY package.json .
COPY yarn.lock .
RUN yarn install --production   <---- THIS DOES NOT INSTALL DEV DEPENENCIES

# Copy app files
COPY . .

# Build the app
RUN yarn build     <---- THIS CAUSES THE CRASHING

# ---------------------------------------------------

# Bundle static assets with nginx
FROM nginx:1.23.1-alpine AS production
ENV NODE_ENV production

# Copy built assets from builder
COPY --from=builder /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html

# Add your nginx.conf
COPY nginx.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf

# Expose port
EXPOSE 80

# Start nginx
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: "3.8"

services:
  app:
    container_name: my_app
    build:
      context: .
      target: production
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the final image stage, you're only `COPY --from=builder` the `/app/build` directory but not any of the `node_modules` tree.  It doesn't matter in the initial stage if you have development or production dependencies, since they're not going to be in the final image.

Since you do need the `devDependencies` at this point, I'd remove the `yarn install --production` option.  If it makes a difference to your build environment you can set `NODE_ENV=production` *after* you install the dependencies.

```bash
RUN yarn install # not --production
COPY . .
# ENV NODE_ENV=production
RUN yarn build
```